# Computer fans Become extremely loud then turn off repeatedly

Tags: windows-10, fan, cooling

My computer of around 5 years now started recently acting funny. Whilst playing Fortnite my PC fans would suddenly start whirring up and being extremely loud, after around 10 seconds they would seem to shut off or start not making sound until around 2 minutes passed where the same issue occurs.

I have cleaned out the PC with an air compressor yet the problem still persists. it does not occur when im not playing games and just watching youtube. I only have fortnite and discord running when playing and i do not have a virus since my hard drive died 3 days ago and i bought a new one installed discord steam epicgames riotgames and chrome and i still run into the same issue.

Please help me as it would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A noisy fan typically occurs when the bearing that holds the fan in place on the shaft of the fan has worn out allowing the fan to move away from its correct position and also rattle and make a loud grating noise. A worn out fan cannot cool the computer efficiently because it runs too slowly due to friction. A slow fan cannot cool the computer properly, which can cause performance to lag and intermittent stop and start performance.

Installing a temperature and fan speed app like [SpeedFan](https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) will help you to diagnose this problem. Usually the solution to a noisy fan problem is to replace the fan.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Are there any compatability checks that need to be made before i just walk out and buy a new fan?

Comment: I start out by putting my ear next to the computer to make sure I know where the noise is coming from. If your computer is a desktop you can open the case, remove the fan and take it with you to buy its replacement. If it's a laptop you can take the laptop with you when you go to buy a replacement fan and maybe someone at the store will install it for you while you wait. If the computer has two fans and both of them are noisy, you can replace both fans.

Comment: Ok thanks although it isnt a grating sound it just spins very fast/loudly

Comment: The fan will start making a grating sound eventually if you don't fix it.